# How to copy files from Amazon EC2 server

Tags: linux, rsync, scp, amazon-web-services

I am desperately trying to copy some files from AWS EC2 machine but I am struggling with following.

- I am able to copy only some files from already existing folder (although I want to to copy all the files recursively to my local machine)
- `scp` and `rsync` complains that path doesn't exist when I create completely new file in some location (let's say `/home/ec2-user/a.txt`)

The command I am using is

```
scp -rpi ~/.ssh/my-key.pem  ec2-user@52.29.216.47:/home/ec2-user/a.txt
```

I created the file under ec2-user with `touch a.txt` so the permissions should be fine (if that even matters).

Contents of original folder I want to copy is

```
-rw-r--r--  1 webapp   webapp     90 17. úno  2015 cron.yaml
drw-r--r--  2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096  1. dub 13.09 db-backup
-rw-r--r--  1 webapp   webapp   2703 17. úno  2015 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 webapp   webapp    189 17. úno  2015 logo_aws_reduced.gif
drwxrwxrwx 15 ec2-user ec2-user 4096  1. dub 17.35 martintour
drw-r--r-- 14 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 30. bře 20.52 master_martintour
-rw-r--r--  1 webapp   webapp    367 17. úno  2015 scheduled.php
-rw-r--r--  1 webapp   webapp   3490 17. úno  2015 styles.css
```

However only this part is copied

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pmensik pmensik   90 úno 17  2015 cron.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 pmensik pmensik 2703 úno 17  2015 index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 pmensik pmensik  189 úno 17  2015 logo_aws_reduced.gif
-rw-r--r-- 1 pmensik pmensik  367 úno 17  2015 scheduled.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 pmensik pmensik 3490 úno 17  2015 styles.css
```

So it seems like the `-r` option is not working. And also it doesn't explain why I cannot copy newly created files or folders like I mentioned previously.

The command I used for this is

```
scp -rpi ~/.ssh/my-key.pem  ec2-user@52.29.216.47:/var/app/current .
```

I've already played with changing the permissions but no I am completely lost.

Comment: in your first command, you're copying from `/home/ec2-user2/a.txt` ie, notice the extra `2` after `ec2-user`. which doesn't correspond to your user

Comment: Just a typo, sorry, it doesn't work even with the right path

Comment: Post exactly what errors you get. Increasing log level (`-vvv`) might help to show more information.

Comment: This is result of the `scp` command https://pastebin.com/RayDETG3

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the destination directory.

Try:

`scp -rp -i ~/.ssh/my-key.pem ec2-user@52.29.216.47:/home/ec2-user/a.txt /your/local/dir/`

Answer (score 2):

Besides destination - permission does matter, because you're logging in to the instance with scp/rsync as ec2-user, not root. Nevertheless, e.g. `cron.yaml` is readable to anyone, this is why it was transferred. Make sure `a.txt` owner is not 'root'.

Try:

`rsync -Hva --progress -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-key.pem" ec2-user@52.29.216.47:/home/ec2-user/ ./`

where `./` is your local destination dir. Note trailing slashes at the end of both paths.

Comment: I tried exactly what you have written and no file other than those created by OS itself were transfered (like `.bashrc`). So it doesn't work though my files has the permissions and owner like the rest of the "system" files. Really don't know what's going on

Comment: Ok, found the solution - I was connection to the wrong machine all time, I mixed up IP addresses in the start and noticed it just now. I am gonna delete the question. Stupid me, thanks anyway :)